# What could be the cause of a randomly slow / fast connection to a WireGuard VPS in Hong Kong from Florida?

Tags: vpn, internet-speed, wireguard

I live in Florida now and have a VPS setup in Hong Kong with wireguard VPN setup. The vps has a 100mbit connection as I did a speed test via ssh and I get about 80-99mbps. What is going wrong here?

[image]

But when I'm on wireguard accessing it from florida, I get at most 15mbps that I have ever seen. Sometimes I get only 1mbps which comes pretty often.

[image]

I'm not sure how can I go about diagnosing this problem as it happens randomly. Is there some type of tool to make this connection more stable? I think due to the long distance I'll never hit close to 90mbps.

Below is my wireguard server conf file:

[image]

And this is my wireguard client conf file:

[image]

---

**iperf test results**

I tested the server / client using iperf and the results are below. It shows only a 2.3mbit from my server to client connection. But the speedtest-cli shows a result of 99mbit. I'm not sure what to do...

[image]

Comment: Can you run IPerf across the FL-HK WireGuard link to measure what that link is capable of by itself? It would help to know the speed in both directions, along with the RTT and the packet error/loss rate.

Comment: I just did a iperf test. It shows only a 2.3mbit connection, but my speedtest-cli shows 99mbit. So I'm not sure how to fix this? Sometimes I get 15mbit, so I'm not sure what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the network buffers significantly reduced the lag. It's still there, but its alot better.

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-tcp-tuning

[image]